# Footer in Liferay

Tags: liferay, themes, footer, liferay-theme

I need to make a footer in Liferay and use theme for it. What's the simpliest way to do it?

I have created new theme, filled `_diffs` folder with other folders, but it's empty and I couldn't find relevant docs about this. Should I copy all basic files there? What should I change to create footer?

Comment: [***CREATING LIFERAY THEMES***](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/creating-liferay-themes)

Comment: `subfolders not created by default`, you have to create these folders manually. [***more***](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/anatomy-of-a-theme)

Comment: For sample, you can look at `classic` theme's structure at `/ROOT/html/themes/classic` in your container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Liferay, theme's `portal_normal.vm` serves as the template to
>   construct HTML structure of the page. There you define your header,
>   body and footer includes.

When you will look at the `portal_normal.vm` of classic theme, you will observe following HTML snippet:

```
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <p class="powered-by">
        #language ("powered-by")
        <a href="http://www.liferay.com" rel="external">Liferay</a>
    </p>
</footer>
```

This is the footer of the page. This is what you need to implement. However, it's not necessary to use `footer` tag at all, as you can simply use `div` or `table` based structure with `bootstrap` or customized `CSS` classes for your footer, it's upto your requirement.

Remember! Classic theme is just like a sample provided by Liferay, so, it's not good idea to directly customize it.

Everybody needs a whole customized view of the site, and for this the best idea is to create a custom theme (that's what you are doing!), that will give you full control over your look-n-feel.

To kick-start, you can initially copy required folders from classic theme to your customized theme's (`_diffs` folder) and start changing bit by bit.

Comment: So I can create new styled theme, copy all files from classic theme into diffs folder and I will have standart theme where I can change color and so on?

Comment: Yes, but there are other `*.vm` files, that are responsible for initialization of  useful theme variables and creating navigation etc. Take a close look at the anatomy of the classic theme.

Comment: Ok. I'll rephrase my question. How can I create changeable classic theme from styled velocity project? What exactly should I do?

Comment: That's good, what you were doing! Create a new theme plugin and completely give new look to your site. Set `<property name="theme.parent" value="_styled" />` in your theme's builder for copying core CSS styles.

Comment: So I need to create new styled velocity theme, set that line (where?) and copy all files from classic theme?

Comment: Yes. Do you use `ant` as builder? This property needs to be set in `build.xml` of theme.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll try this out and write smth here! Yes, I use ant.

Comment: I have one question left: what do you mean "This is what you need to implement."? I found that footer's code, but how can I change it? Sorry for my dumb questions :D

Comment: I meant that, if you want to show footer on your website, then you need to implement something like this. See, `portal_normal.vm` is a template, which may be divided into certain sections, i.e. `head` tag for including JS and CSS resources, in `body` you may have, top-bar, navigation, breadcrumb, portlet drop-area and then footer.

Comment: Its all about the placement, if you put certain HTML at the top, it becomes header, and it you put something at the bottom, if becomes footer (applied specific styling). But, there are other mandatory includes, like `$theme.include($top_head_include)`, `$theme.include($body_top_include)`, `$theme.include($content_include)`, `$theme.include($body_bottom_include)`, and `$theme.include($bottom_include)`, which you can't skip, otherwise core features of Liferay won't work.

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand. I have a footer code in portal_normal.vm in `_diffs/templates/` folder. Why there is no footer on my page?

Comment: Open browser debugger tool and see, if it is getting rendered in HTML. Look for CSS, may be hiding it.

Comment: All I did was: 1) Create classic velocity theme 2) Create _styled velocity theme 3) Paste all 4 folders from classic theme into `_diffs` styled theme's folder 4) Choose my styled theme in Liferay Portal. 

Btw, why I should have footer if I don't have it in classic theme? May be I should do smth more?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I get it!! Thanks a lot. But how can I change the color ?

Comment: Of my footer. MOreover, I need to make my footer responsive, I mean, It should be shown correctly after resizing

Comment: Report this in a separate question with your footer's HTML, so that I can help you out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634673/color-and-other-footers-parameters-in-liferay