# Color and other footer's parameters in Liferay

Tags: liferay, footer, liferay-theme

I need to create footer which will be just like small orange bar, and I need to make it responsive, I mean when I resized my window everything should be ok. How can I do that?

```
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <p class="powered-by">
        #language ("powered-by German") 
    </p>
</footer>
```

This is my `<footer>` tag in `portal_normal.vm`

[image]

Comment: Show your HTML code? Are you using bootstrap classes?

Comment: @ParkashKumar what do you mean "HTML code"? All I've done is created new styled velocity theme, copied all files from classic themes into diffes folder and found <footer> tag.

Comment: I meant you to show your original `footer` code.

Comment: @ParkashKumar I've already post it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your `footer` responsive, you can use Liferay supported [**Twitter Bootstrap**](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.3.2/docs/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) classes, aided by your own custom styles controlled through [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in `custom.css` of theme:

**Example:**

```
<div id="footer" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 text-center">
        <p class="powered-by">
            #language ("powered-by German")
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[***Liferay Reference***](https://web.liferay.com/web/jorge.ferrer/blog/-/blogs/new-in-6-2-bootstrap-even-in-web-content)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Btw, can I make my footer be in the bottom of page? Not in the end of my content, but in the end of browser's window?

Comment: Add `position: relative;` and `bottom: 0;` to `#footer` in `custom.css`

Comment: No, I have the same footer's location. ;(

Comment: Sorry, it will be `position: absolute;` [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dkjy2mh1/)

Comment: I also think that it should work, but look again at my updated post.

Comment: Ok, the other way around is to set `min-height` to your content area. Adjust it according to your requirement.

Comment: See [**this**](http://www.lwis.net/profile/CSS/sticky-footer.html) for a reference.

Answer (score 1):

In my `custom.css` I write this:

```
#footer {
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffa500
}
```

and get orange centered footer.