# Sticky footer in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, footer, sticky-footer, liferay-theme

How to create sticky footer in Liferay? I've read a lot of docs but all of them haven't worked.

I have this in `custom.css`

```
#footer {
     background-color: black;
     color: white; 
     font-size: 200%; 
     text-align: center; 
     line-height: 3em; 
     clear: both;
     position: relative; 
     z-index: 10; 
     height: 3em;
     margin-top: -3em;
}
```

and this in `portal_normal.vm`:

```
<div id="footer">Powered by German</div>
```

In mentioned previous question I asked how to create footer and change it color. Then, in the comment, I asked how to create sticky footer and got no good answer, so I created another thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color and other footer's parameters in Liferay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634673/color-and-other-footers-parameters-in-liferay)

Comment: No. In my previous question I asked how to make footer and how to change it's color. In this theme I'm trying to understand how to make sticky one.

Comment: In that case I misunderstood the phrase `I need to make it responsive` in your previous question. By the way - this is not Liferay specific and I'm sure that one of the answers in [sticky-footer](/questions/tagged/sticky-footer) will help you - so still a duplicate.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke you can try out all of them and none will work.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke There is a difference between sticky and responsive footers, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem!!!

First of all, you should look at this line: `<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">` in `portlet_normal.vm`:

Our footer into this category, so that every time will be not in the end of browser page but in the end of this block. So you need to close that block and place footer below:

```
<div id="footer" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 text-center">
        <p class="powered-by">
            #language ("Powered by Alexandr Boldyrev")
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then, you should change footer's parameter in `custom.css`:

```
#footer {
     text-align: center;
     background: #FFEFD5;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
}
```

That is it, our footer becomes sticky!